# How to get html passed as a variable from python flask into html?

Tags: python, flask

In this example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, session
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="secret"

@app.route('/')
def landing():
    session['results']="<p>Test one</p>"
    session['results']+="<p>Test two</p>"
    results=session['results']
    return render_template('index.html', results=results)

app.run(debug='True')
```

In my html, I have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {{ results }}

    </body>
</html>
```

The results are an html page that does not interpret the

tags.  So, I get a page that looks like this:

```
<p>Test One</p><p>Test Two</p>
```

Comment: What you are doing is hard, because it really isn't something you should be doing. It has the potential to introduce security problems in your application, for example if 'session['results'] contained '<script src="http://hacksRus.example.com/badstuff.js" type="text/javascript" /><p>Not up to mischief, honest.</p>'. A better approach would be to keep the HTML in the template file: iterate over the items in results, and wrap them in 'p' tags in the template.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Makes perfect sense.  In this instance, the code on the backend is the only code that updates that dictionary.  It isn't user controlled.  But I will see about using your method.  I am super new to python, and flask.  I could do this easily in javascript ;)

Comment: BTW...  Would you mind sharing how you would structure the process you are describing?

Comment: Did you tried `{{results|safe}}`

Comment: {% for result in results %}
    <p>{{ result }}</p>
{% endfor %} instead of just {{ results }}. The templating language is Jinja, AFAIK, and you can read about that here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Many thanks!  If you put that as an answer, I would mark it as the solution

Answer (score 5):

You could escape the HTML:

```
{{ results|safe}}
```

or  in Python

```
import jinja2
results = jinja2.escape(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

The framework is escaping the HTML in the results variable to prevent security holes. Ideally you want to keep the HTML in the template and not be passed in via the variables. The best way to achieve what you want is to iterate over the values in results variable and wrap it in p tags in the template. This can be done like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {% for result in results %}
        <p>{{ result }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The templating language is Jinja2, and you can read about that here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from flask import Markup
results = Markup(results)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will improve the answer's long-term value.